# SGS running CyanogenMod 10 headphone volume cap

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, volume

Is there a way to increase the max volume cap for SGS running CM10, please?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "cap"? ("max volume cap")

Comment: Volume cap means volume limit ~ max volume level.

Comment: Are you concerned with the volume in headphones or from the speakers?

Comment: Headphones. (title)

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the CM DSP app ?